# Get Amount Back After Removed Swift 3

Tags: swift

I have a quiz app and the result look like this
[image]

When I click try again the question starts again. But I can't do that because in my code I removed a number question after the question appear

```
func pickQuestion() {
    if Questions.count > 0 {

        QNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(Questions.count)))
        textView.text = Questions[QNumber].Question
        AnswerNumber = Questions[QNumber].Answer
        for i in 0..<Buttons.count {
            Buttons[i].setTitle(Questions[QNumber].Answers[i], for: UIControlState.normal)
        }
        Questions.remove(at: QNumber) //here
    }
```

how to get the number back so I can start question from the beginning? Sorry, but I'm really new to swift and programming.

Comment: why do you remove it as soon as its picked and not when its answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A possible solution would be to have two separate arrays.

One array for all your questions, and other for using in-game. Each time you start a game, you should create a new array that is the exact copy of the array with all your questions.

When you press try again, it will create a new array that's identical to the base array with all the answers and it will manipulate the copied array instead of the main one.

By the way, try to format your questions more clearly, because I'm not sure if I answered your question or not :\

Answer (score 1):

As per my opinion take one `Question` class object and integer `temIndex`  for temporary store such like

```
var temQuestionObj: Question!
let temIndex : Int = 0
```

And store your random question in the `temQuestionObj`  such like

```
func pickQuestion() 
{
    if Questions.count > 0 
   {

        QNumber = Int(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(Questions.count)))

         temQuestionObj = Questions[QNumber] // TEMPORARY store this Question.
         temIndex =  QNumber /// TEMPORARY store current index.

        textView.text = Questions[QNumber].Question
        AnswerNumber = Questions[QNumber].Answer
        for i in 0..<Buttons.count {
            Buttons[i].setTitle(Questions[QNumber].Answers[i], for: UIControlState.normal)
        }
        Questions.remove(at: QNumber) //here
}
```

So when you click on **"Try Again"** you can also reuse/Add your `temQuestionObj` class on specific `temIndex` in the `Questions` Array.

Such like

```
Questions.insert(temQuestionObj, atIndex:temIndex)
```

So you can reuse your question without loss index.